# cors enabled axios get request getting failed

Tags: javascript, cors, axios

having 2 api's. method POST-Login method GET-data. and server has cors enabled. Login api working fine, but when call api with GET method it gets failed. 
Code:

->api Login-POST

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  console.log("in auth service");
  const userDetail = {
    username:email,
    // email,
    password
  };

  try {
    // unsetHeadersWithUserToken();
    const afterSuccess = await api.post(apiDetail.auth.url,  userDetail); 

    if (afterSuccess) {
      return afterSuccess.data;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error.response.error);
    if (error.category === 'User Permissions') {
      // forceLogout();
    }
    throw error;
  }
};
```

->api-GET

```
try{
    // console.log("url : ", apiDetail.partnerLocations.url);
let token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
setHeadersWithUserToken(token);
    let apiResponse = await api.get(apiDetail.partnerLocations.url);
    return apiResponse;
}catch(error){
    console.info('##### demand-response.js:11 #####');
    console.info('========================= Start =========================');
    console.error('error = ', JSON.stringify(error));
    // console.log(error.response.data)
    console.info('========================== End ==========================');
    throw error;
}
```

->axios call

```
   import axios from 'axios';
import { environment } from '../../utils/constants';

let api;
let apiDetail = {
  baseURL: environment.baseURL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
};
const setAPI = apiDetail => {
  api = axios.create(apiDetail);
};
setAPI(apiDetail);
const setHeadersWithUserToken = token => {
  api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
};
export {
  api,
  setHeadersWithUserToken,
};
```

Image-1
[image]
showing console error

Image-2
[image]
network call response

Comment: It seems you have `access-control-allow-origin: *` in your REQUEST header..  It needs to be in your server RESPONSE header.

Comment: @BryanElliott using chrome extension for this, 
got this error "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status"

Comment: Yes, the server RESPONSE needs to have `access-control-allow-origin: *` in the header. (Response header, not request header)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
cosnt url = 'Your URL'
axios.get(proxyurl + url)
```

I faced the same issue and this works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Add the "proxy" property (found at the bottom here) to package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:<PORT-GOES-HERE>"
```

Now, instead of making HTTP requests like this:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/example")
```

You should write them like this:

```
axios.get("/example")
```

Comment: You can install CORS plugins for Chrome ("Moesif COR"S or "Allow CORS") or also you can add your front-end domain to allow hosts on your back-end.

Comment: chrome extension is working for POST request, but not for GET request.